# How can I execute an aspx from url returning an ContentType Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This function return an resized and centered image.
I would like tu execute it like **thumb.aspx?image=test.jpg&width=100&height=50&needToFill=tru‌​e** to get a **ContentType = "image/jpeg"**

```
public static System.Drawing.Image FixedSize(Image image, int Width, int Height, bool needToFill)
{
    int sourceWidth = image.Width;
    int sourceHeight = image.Height;
    int sourceX = 0;
    int sourceY = 0;
    double destX = 0;
    double destY = 0;
    double nScale = 0;
    double nScaleW = 0;
    double nScaleH = 0;
    nScaleW = ((double)Width / (double)sourceWidth);
    nScaleH = ((double)Height / (double)sourceHeight);
    if (!needToFill)
    {
        nScale = Math.Min(nScaleH, nScaleW);
    }
    else
    {
        nScale = Math.Max(nScaleH, nScaleW);
        destY = (Height - sourceHeight * nScale) / 2;
        destX = (Width - sourceWidth * nScale) / 2;
    }
    if (nScale > 1)
        nScale = 1;
    int destWidth = (int)Math.Round(sourceWidth * nScale);
    int destHeight = (int)Math.Round(sourceHeight * nScale);

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmPhoto = null;
    try
    {
        bmPhoto = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(destWidth + (int)Math.Round(2 * destX), destHeight + (int)Math.Round(2 * destY));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("destWidth:{0}, destX:{1}, destHeight:{2}, desxtY:{3}, Width:{4}, Height:{5}",
            destWidth, destX, destHeight, destY, Width, Height), ex);
    }
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics grPhoto = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto))
    {
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        grPhoto.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        grPhoto.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        Rectangle to =  new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)Math.Round(destX), (int)Math.Round(destY), destWidth, destHeight);
        Rectangle from = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
        grPhoto.DrawImage(image, to, from, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        return bmPhoto;
    }
}
```

Can I just add this in somehow?

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e){
```

Comment: You can create an HTTP Handler. Take a look at [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) for more information.

Comment: for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34084/Generic-Image-Handler-Using-IHttpHandler

Comment: Can't be done just in a single file thumb.aspx?

Comment: I reverted the question. Your new edit changes the question to a new one. If you have a totally new question ask a new one. Currently I posted an answer which shows you how to use a **aspx** or **ashx** to return an image. I kept the answer simple because I have no Idea about the method which you are using, but you can use any logic to create your image, like I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an HTTP Handler to satisfy such requirement. An ASP.NET HTTP handler is the process (frequently referred to as the "endpoint") that runs in response to a request made to an ASP.NET Web application. To learn more, take a look at [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)

**ASHX Example**

To process a request like this: `http://localhost:19610/ImageHandler.ashx?width=200&height=200`

1. Add a new  Generic Handler (.ashx) to project and name it `ImageHandler.ashx`
2. Write code to get parameters from query string and perform processing and return suitable response:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WebApplication1 /*use your application namespace*/
{
    public class ImageHandler: IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            int width = 0;
            int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["width"], out width);
            var height = 0;
            int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["height"], out height);
            if (width <= 0) width = 100;
            if (height <= 0) height = 100;
            using (var image = new Bitmap(width, height))
            {
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
                    g.Clear(Color.Red);
                byte[] buffer = 
                    (byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
    }
}
```

**ASPX Example**

If for any reason you want to use an *aspx* instead, you can create a aspx file without any code behind file like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int width = 0;
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["width"], out width);
        var height = 0;
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["height"], out height);
        if (width <= 0) width = 100;
        if (height <= 0) height = 100;
        using (var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(image))
                g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            byte[] buffer =
            (byte[])new System.Drawing.ImageConverter().ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
            Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's an example to keep things simple. You should apply your logic in `ImageHandler.` These `ashx` handlers are like `aspx` handlers, but ashx handler is useful for creating such custom output. They are like ASP.NET MVC actions.

Comment: It's a different question. Your first question was asking *I would like to execute it like **thumb.aspx**?* and the answer is: *Simply use **thumb.ashx***

Comment: The answer shows you how to write an *ashx* handler. Use the example and see the result. In next step if you have any specific question about your code, ask a new question about it. For example why that value is null is a different question :)

Comment: That's why I keep the example simple, to be able to test it simply and let us to focus to a single problem in this post: *execute it like **thumb.aspx*** :)

Comment: Exactly the way which you run a aspx: Type this address in address bar: `http://yoursiteurl/ImageHandler.ashx?width=200&height=200`

Comment: Also if you want to see a usage in an html/aspx page you can use the address as src of an image tag.

Comment: Yes I edited your question because it made the answer nonsense. I see you asked a new question. That's the correct way. Please keep each question specific to a single topic and don't mix multiple problems in a single question.